# Slow lagging Blender

Tags: performance

I'm fairly new to Blender. I'm working on a sculpted character. Since I have started using the dyntopo and resolution I get the wheel of death at almost every command! So I can't really continue! I'm using version 2.92.My pc otherwise works fine, so it's just Blender that is frustratingly slow!

Comment: Hi, this really isn't a question anyone can answer.  Would you like to edit it to make it into such a question?

Comment: It could be that your sculpted character has too many vertices and your PC can't handle it. But it's impossible to tell without more information/screenshots.

Comment: After some figuring out, I now think that is the problem. Too much detail. Thanks!